# Using Tridion Core Services how to obtain Members of group in which Group memberships obtained from an external (LDAP) directory?

Tags: 2013-sp1, core-service, event-system

My Idea is to get the list of users for particular project in Tridion Publication using Core Services. I tried to get it from `GroupMembershipData`. But unfortunatly it is not  including Group memberships obtained from an external (LDAP) directory.

So I am trying to get the Group Id using below code. But I am getting Object Reference Null error in the following line :

```
GroupData group = (GroupData)_client.Read(id, new ReadOptions());
```

I understood the ID which I am passing is not correct. Because `GroupData` is inheriting `TrusteeData`. So I can't assign the child to Parent. So please help me to get the Publication ID of Group Members and Users for specific project.

```
protected void UserProjectUserCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ICoreService _client = Utility.GetCoreServiceSettings();
    PublicationsFilterData filterData = new PublicationsFilterData();
    var publicationList = _client.GetSystemWideListXml(filterData);
    PopulateProjectSpecificUserList(publicationList);
}

private void PopulateProjectSpecificUserList(XElement publicationList)
{
    string PublicationID = "";
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    string results = string.Empty;
    IEnumerable<XElement> elementList = publicationList.Elements();
    foreach(XElement elem in elementList)
    {
        if (elem.Attribute("Title").Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains("polo") && elem.Attribute("Title").Value.ToString().Trim().StartsWith("05"))
        {
            PublicationID = elem.Attribute("ID").Value.ToString();
        }
    }
    ICoreService _client = Utility.GetCoreServiceSettings();
    PublicationData pub = (PublicationData)_client.Read(PublicationID, null);

    AccessControlListData t =  pub.AccessControlList;

    string id = string.Empty;       
    foreach(var usrGroups in t.AccessControlEntries)
    {
        id = usrGroups.Trustee.IdRef;
    }           

    GroupData group = (GroupData)_client.Read(id, new ReadOptions());

    var searchDn = ((DirectoryGroupMappingData)group.ClaimMappings.First()).SearchDN;
    var directoryServiceName = ((DirectoryGroupMappingData)group.ClaimMappings.FirstOrDefault()).DirectoryServiceName;
    var result = _client.GetListDirectoryServiceGroupMembers(directoryServiceName, searchDn);

    TridionItemList.DocumentContent = result.ToString();
    TridionItemList.TransformSource = Server.MapPath(@".\ProjectSpecificUserList.xslt"); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LDAP group memberships are not in Tridion, so why try to get them out of Tridion? You should query the LDAP server to get this information.

Of course, you'll also probably want to communicate with Tridion to get the information which *is* there.

Comment: So what is your Conclusion then?

Comment: That you should query the LDAP server directly

Comment: Yes, Dominic is correct, TridionCoreService will get the Tridion Groups not the LDAP Groups

Comment: Thank you so much @Dominic Cronin and @ Chris Mills. But my aim is to get the Groups from Tridion only. Let see in future may be in web-9 there are giving this future are not. Thank you so much. Will get back to you in future if anything required.